# How to add a folder of Hosting to a Domain

Tags: domain-name, web-hosting

I am new in domain transfer. Previously my domain was in Bluehost. I transferred the domain to GoDaddy. I changed the Nameservers. Now I would like to add a folder of hosting to that domain. I got below error message while I tried to do this.

[image]

Comment: *a folder of hosting* would you clarify this? I am unable to guess what you mean.

Comment: Thanks @GiantTree for your comment. I have a folder in my hosting, I would like to attach it with the domain name. That means if I browse the domain name index.html file of the folder will execute. Thanks

Comment: A file or folder is not part of your domain. To access the website, run a web server (Apache, nginx) on the server with the IP address you configured.

Comment: @GiantTree I know that. I would like to access the website using domain name. Thanks

Comment: Just point the domain to your server's IP address and configure the ServerName to be your hostname (only needed with SSL or multiple hosts on one IP)